# Unwanted Viewport clipping even after scale with SVG

Tags: html, svg

I'm getting some undesired clipping on the top of my viewport. The it looks like if any part of an svg element is out side of it's viewport it will stay cropped even when scaled. Is there any way to disable this to get the effect that I want in the third group?

http://jsbin.com/ukujad/5/edit?html,live

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect class="bg" height="100%" width="100%" />

  <!-- what i get -->
  <g transform="translate(0, 400) scale(1, -0.5)">
    <svg x="10%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="350px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
    <svg x="10%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
  </g>

  <!-- how it looks with out the scale -->
  <g transform="translate(0, 400) scale(1, -1)">
    <svg x="40%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="350px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
    <svg x="40%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
  </g>

  <!-- what i want -->
  <g transform="translate(0, 400) scale(1, -1)">
    <svg x="70%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="175px" height="50px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
    <svg x="70%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0px" height="50px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add overflow="visible"

```
  <g transform="translate(0, 400) scale(1, -0.5)">
    <svg x="10%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%" overflow="visible">
      <rect x="0" y="350px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
    <svg x="10%" y="0px" width="20%" height="100%" overflow="visible">
      <rect x="0" y="0px" height="100px" width="100%" />
    </svg>
  </g>
```

Comment: face + palm. I just keep goggling something to do with clipping. It can also be applied as a style!